# how to bind angular components with ui-router

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to test angular v1.6.2 components and ui-router together but can't get it to work. Here is my

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="rrrwamac">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- <test></test> -->
        <ui-view></ui-view>

        <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

component:

```
angular.module('rrrwamac').component('test', {
  template:  '<h3>Its the UI-Router<br>testing..!</h3>'
})
```

and config:

```
var app = angular.module('rrrwamac', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('test', {
            url: '',
            component: 'test'
        });
});
```

NOTE: When I place component tag

```
<test></test>
```

everything works, but when I try using ui-router and ui-view it doesn't.

I am also using live-server that places an extra script into my html and connects to http://127.0.0.1:8080/.
Any help greatly appreciated. Thanx.

Comment: Check your log, it might be a silly typo somewhere, your code works fine: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NdOOKE

Comment: My God. Thank u kind sir for posting this into codepen. It proved that my code is good so I've started searching for mistake elsewhere. It turned out that npm did not install the latest version of ui router. I thought that it always does if u won't specify any version. Silly mistake